# Migration from VS 2008 to VS 2010 Assembly Reference Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks

I am converting a 2008 solution to visual studio 2010. I was able to build my `DAL` and `BAL`. But unfortunately I am not able to build the website in the solution.  the below

Error during compilation.

```
Assembly 'ABC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.ServiceModel, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 
'System.ServiceModel, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Though  I have added `System.ServiceModel 4.0` in the project, I am still getting the same error.

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: It's looking for version 3, not 4.

Comment: Found out the issue. I didn't update the version in web.config, it was referring to version 3.0.

Added the below line in web.config and its found to be working fine

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">

Comment: Good job figuring it out! Just so you know, you can answer your own question `;)`